# Selecting two conditions simultaneously

Tags: mysql, sql

Say i've got the next to tables: Doctors, and Workdays:

```
 DocNumbers  | idNum  
  118        | 11    
  119        | 12      
  120        | 13       
  121        | 14       
  122        | 15
```

Notice: a doctor can work in several different workdays.

```
 DocNum  | Workday    |AmountOfHours |
  118    |   1        |     8        |
  118    |   3        |     9        |
  120    |   1        |     6        |
  121    |   3        |     5        | 
  122    |   4        |     7        |
```

I want to create a new table containing all id's of the doctors that work in day 1 and day 3 - That means that i will get a table containing only 118.

So far i've got:

```
SELECT distinct Doctors.doctorNumber, idNum
FROM Doctors, Workdays
WHERE Workdays.dayInWeek in (1,3)
AND Workdays.doctorNumber=Doctors.doctorNumber
```

But it seems like a i get irrelevant results like 120 and 121.
So 'IN' is more like a 'OR'. Can't seem to find the equivalence for 'and'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to do if you join the Workdays table twice, once for each day you want to check:

```
select Doctors.DocNumbers, Doctors.idNum
from Doctors
inner join Workdays as Workdays1 on Workdays1.DocNum = Doctors.DocNumbers and Workdays1.Workday = 1
inner join Workdays as Workdays3 on Workdays3.DocNum = Doctors.DocNumbers and Workdays3.Workday = 3;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c530/3

Comment: Just for the sake of understanding:
You've created two 'new' tables, One contains all the doctors with day 1. The other contains all the doctors with day 3. How exactly does it all mix together?

Comment: @TheCatcherInTheRye Doctors contains all doctors. The inner join with Workdays1 filters out all the doctors that don't work on day 1. The inner join work Workdays3 filters out all the doctors that don't work on day 3. So only the doctors that work on both days remain.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with simple join

```
SELECT DISTINCT w.`DocNum`, d.idNum
FROM doctors d
LEFT JOIN  Workdays w ON(d.`DocNumbers`=w.`DocNum`)
LEFT JOIN  Workdays ww ON(d.`DocNumbers`=ww.`DocNum`)
WHERE w.`Workday` = 1 AND ww.`Workday` =3
```

<kbd>[**See fiddle here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/735c6/2)</kbd>

Here is another way of doing same

```
SELECT  w.`DocNum`, d.idNum
FROM doctors d
LEFT JOIN  Workdays w ON(d.`DocNumbers`=w.`DocNum`)
GROUP BY d.`DocNumbers`
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(w.`Workday`  SEPARATOR ',')= '1,3'
```

<kbd>[**See fiddle here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/735c6/3)</kbd>

Comment: Heh, you edited and undeleted your answer at pretty much the same moment I posted mine. I don't think `LEFT JOIN` has a benefit here: since you're filtering on columns in both `w` and `ww`, it has the same effect as an `INNER JOIN` anyway, and I've been told that MySQL handles `INNER JOIN`s much better than `LEFT JOIN`s (though I've never benchmarked myself)

Comment: @hvd yup first i did with single join but then i realize it gives two records so i deleted my post and edited with newer version, and for left join i agree with you